# React-Bootstrap Overlay with Popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I was trying to use React-Bootstrap's [overlay with Popup](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/overlays).

Here is the example from the documentation:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Overlay from 'react-bootstrap/Overlay';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';

function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [target, setTarget] = useState(null);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setShow(!show);
    setTarget(event.target);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Holy guacamole!</Button>

      <Overlay
        show={show}
        target={target}
        placement="bottom"
        container={ref}
        containerPadding={20}
      >
        <Popover id="popover-contained">
          <Popover.Header as="h3">Popover bottom</Popover.Header>
          <Popover.Body>
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
          </Popover.Body>
        </Popover>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I tried the following:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Overlay, Popover } from "react-bootstrap";

const SimpleMRE: React.FC = () => {
    const container = useRef(null)
    const [target, setTarget] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const timeout = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined>()

    function onMouseOut(e: React.MouseEvent): void {
        timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setShow(false)
        }, 1500)
    }

    function onMouseOver(e: React.MouseEvent): void {
        if (timeout.current) {
            clearTimeout(timeout.current)
        }

        setTarget(e.target as HTMLElement)
        setShow(true)
    }
    
    return (
        <div ref={container}>
            <a onMouseOver={onMouseOver} onMouseOut={onMouseOut} href="www.google.com">Link to my resource</a>

            <Overlay show={show} target={target} placement="top" container={container} containerPadding={20}>
                <Popover id="testPopover">
                    <Popover.Header>Some lovely header</Popover.Header>
                    <Popover.Body>Some lovely body</Popover.Body>
                </Popover>
            </Overlay>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SimpleMRE
```

However, when I hover over the link, nothing happens at all - the popup doesn't appear and nothing is displayed in the console.

Even when I use code that's essentially identical to their example, nothing happens:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Overlay, Popover } from "react-bootstrap";

const SimpleMRE: React.FC = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [target, setTarget] = useState(null);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const handleClick = (event: any) => {
        setShow(!show);
        setTarget(event.target);
    };

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>Holy guacamole!</Button>

            <Overlay
                show={show}
                target={target}
                placement="bottom"
                container={ref}
                containerPadding={20}
            >
                <Popover id="popover-contained">
                    <Popover.Header as="h3">Popover bottom</Popover.Header>
                    <Popover.Body>
                        <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
                    </Popover.Body>
                </Popover>
            </Overlay>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SimpleMRE;
```

I am able to use other React-Bootstrap components just fine. In fact, if I try to use their Popup with no Overlay, it works just fine; however, I can't do that because it covers the text, which I don't want, and the documentation says that I need to use an overlay in order to be able to place it.

I'm at somewhat of a loss as to what to try next, or even how to debug this further. Does anyone have suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you expecting a tooltip or a popup?

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara Popup.